# Memory usage of pass by value vs. pass by reference

Tags: memory, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

For the past few days am trying to learn if pass by value and pass by reference impact the memory differently. Googling this query, people kept repeating themselves about a copy being created in terms of pass by value and how the original value is affected in terms pass by reference. But I was wondering if someone could zero in on the memory part.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of C++ and JAVA

Answer (score 2):

This question actually depends heavily on the particular language as some allow you to be explicit and define when you want to pass a variable by value and when by reference and some do it always the same way for different types of variables.

A quite popular type of behavior is to use passing by value (by default) for simple times: like int, string, long, float, double, bool etc.

Let us show the memory impact on a theoretical language:

```
int $myVariable = 5;
```

at this moment you have created a one variable in memory which takes the size required to store an integer (let us say 32 bits).

Now you want to pass it to a function:

```
function someFunction(int parameter)
{
    printOnScreen(parameter);
}
```

so your code would look like:

```
function someFunction(int $parameter)
{
    printOnScreen($parameter);
}

int $myVariable = 5; //Position A
someFunction($myVariable); //Position B
...rest of the code //Position C
```

Since simple types are passed by value the value is copied in memory to another storage place - therefore:

during Position A you have memory occupied by ONE int (with value 5);
during Position B you have memory occupied by TWO ints (with values of 5) as your $myVariable was copied in memory
during Position C you have again memory occupied by ONE int (with value of 5) as the second one was already destroyed as it was needed only for the time of execution of the function

This has some other implications: modifications on a variable passed by value DO NOT affect the original variable - for example:

```
function someFunction(int $parameter)
{
    $parameter = $parameter + 1;
    printOnScreen($parameter);
}

int $myVariable = 5; //Position A
someFunction($myVariable); //Position B
printOnScreen($myVariable); //Position C
```

During position A you set value of 5 under variable $myVariable.
During position B you pass it BY VALUE to a function which adds 1 to your passed value. YET since it was a simple type, passed by value, it actually operates on a LOCAL variable, a COPY of your variable. Therefore position C will again write just 5 (your original variable as it was not modified).

Some languages allow you to be explicit and inform that you want to pass a reference and not the value itself using a special operator -for example `&`. So let us again follow the same example but with explicit info that we want a reference (in function's arguments 
 - note the `&`):

```
function someFunction(int &$parameter)
{
    $parameter = $parameter + 1;
    printOnScreen($parameter);
}

int $myVariable = 5; //Position A
someFunction($myVariable); //Position B
printOnScreen($myVariable); //Position C
```

This time operation and memory implications will be different.

During Position A an int is created (every variable is always consisted of two elements: place in memory and a pointer, an identifier which place is it. For ease of the process let us say that pointer is always one byte). So whenever you create a variable you actually create two things:

- reserved place in memory for the VALUE (in this case 32 bits as it was an int)
- pointer (8 bits [1 byte])

Now during position B, the function expects A POINTER to a memory place. Which means that it will locally, for itself create only a copy of the pointer (1 byte) and not copy the actual reserved place as the new pointer WILLL POINT to the same place as the original one. This means that during operation of the function you have:

TWO POINTERS to an int in memory
ONE place reserved for VALUE of the int
Both of those pointer POINT to the same VALUE

Which means that any modification of the value will affect both.

So looking at the same example position C will not print out also 6 as inside the function we have modified the value under the SAME POINTER as $myVariable.

For COMPLEX TYPES (objects) the default action in most programming environments is to pass the reference (pointer).

So for example - if you have a class:

```
class Person {
   public string $name;
}
```

and create an instance of it and set a value:

```
$john = new Person();
$john->name = "John Malkovic";
```

and later pass it to a function:

```
function printName(Person $instanceOfPerson) 
{
   printOnScreen($instanceOfPerson);
}
```

in terms of memory it will again create only a new POINTER in memory (1 byte) which points to the same value. So having a code like this:

```
function printName(Person $instanceOfPerson) 
{
   printOnScreen($instanceOfPerson);
}

$john = new Person(); // position A
printName($john); // position B
...rest of the code // position C
```

during position A you have: 1 Person (which means 1 pointer [1 byte] to a place in memory which has size to store an object of class person)

during position B you have: 2 pointers [2 bytes] but STILL one place in memory to store an object of class person's value [instance]

during position C you have again situation from position A

I hope that this clarifies the topic for you - generally there is more to cover and what I have mentioned above is just a general explanation.

Comment: Dude I really appreciate your answer. This solution is choice. But I had quick question for you . - what did you mean when you said that whenever you create a varible you create 2 things a space in the memory and a pointer. Well, isn't that a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Pass-by-value and pass-by-reference are language semantics concepts; they don't imply anything about the implementation. Usually, languages that have pass-by-reference implement it by passing a pointer by value, and then when you read or write to the variable inside the function, the compiler translates it into reading or writing from a dereference of the pointer. So you can imagine, for example, if you have a function that takes a parameter by reference in C++:

```
struct Foo { int x; }
void bar(Foo &f) {
    f.x = 42;
}
Foo a;
bar(a);
```

it is really syntactic sugar for something like:

```
struct Foo { int x; }
void bar(Foo *f_ptr) {
    (*f_ptr).x = 42;
}
Foo a;
bar(&a);
```

And so passing by reference has the same cost as passing a pointer by value, which does involve a "copy", but it's the copy of a pointer, which is a few bytes, regardless of the size of the thing pointed to.

When you talk about pass-by-value doing a "copy", that doesn't really tell you much unless you know what exactly the variable or value passed represents in the language. For example, Java only has pass-by-value. But every type in Java is either a primitive type or a reference type, and the values of reference types are "reference", i.e. pointers to objects. So you can never have a value in Java (what a variable holds or what an expression evaluates to) which "is" an "object"; objects in Java can only be manipulated through these "references" (pointers to objects). So when you ask the cost of passing a object in Java, it's actually wrong because you cannot "pass" an object in Java; you can only pass references (pointers to objects), and the copy the happens for pass-by-value, is the copy of the pointer, which is a few bytes.

So the only case where you would actually copy a big structure when passing, is if you have a language where objects or structs are values directly (not behind a reference), and you do pass-by-reference of that object/struct type. So for example, in C++, you can have objects which are values directly, or you can have pointers to them, and you can pass them by value or by reference:

```
struct Foo { int x; }
void bar1(Foo f1) { } // pass Foo by value; this copies the entire size of Foo
void bar2(Foo *f2) { } // pass pointer by value; this copies the size of a pointer
void bar3(Foo &f3) { } // pass Foo by reference; this copies the size of a pointer
void bar4(Foo *&f4) { } // pass pointer by reference; this copies the size of a pointer
```

(Of course, each of those have different semantic meanings; for example, the last one allows the code inside the function to modify the pointer variable passed to point to somewhere else. But if you are concerned about the amount copied. Only the first one is different. In Java, effectively only the second one is possible.)